# AttributeError:'str' object has no attribute 'unique' (Pandas.unique)

Tags: pandas, pyinstaller, exe, series, attributeerror

In my script, I use pandas module. When I execute my file.py - everything works well. But I've converted my file.py to file.exe with auto-py-to-exe and got an error: AttributeError:'str' object has no attribute 'unique'. It's strange because it worked normally. The line where becomes an error: wells=list(file[0].unique()). Who knows this issue, please help.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as fd
import pandas as pd
import os
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, date
import numpy as np
pd.set_option('display.notebook_repr_html', False)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 80)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 200)
pd.set_option('display.width', 800)

def resource_path(relative_path):
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

def open():
    global file_excel, name
    file_excel = fd.askopenfilename(initialdir='/Desktop',     title='Открыть файл', filetypes = [("Excel", "*.xlsx")])
    name = os.path.basename(file_excel)
    name=os.path.splitext(name)[0]
    file_excel=pd.read_excel(file_excel, skiprows=[0], header=None)
    win.destroy()
    return file_excel, name

win = tk.Tk()
path = resource_path("image.png")
photo = tk.PhotoImage(file=path)
win.iconphoto(False, photo)
win.config(bg='#FFC')
win.title('Конвертация в формат .ev')
win.geometry('400x130+500+500')
win.resizable(False, False)

label_1 = tk.Label(win, text = 'Выберите файл с испытаниями скважин:',
                  bg = '#FFC',
                  font=('Arial', 10, 'bold'),
                  padx=20,
                  pady=10).pack()
btn_1 = tk.Button(win, text = 'Выбрать Excel', 
                 command = open,
                 activebackground = '#6F6',
                 font=('Arial', 12, 'bold'),
                 padx=20,
                 pady=10,  
                 relief = tk.RAISED,
                 bd=2).pack()
win.mainloop()

wells=list(file_excel[0].unique())
file_excel[1] = pd.to_datetime(file_excel[1],   errors='coerce').dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
file_excel[4] = np.where(file_excel[1].str, 'Perforation', np.nan)
file_excel.iloc[:,[2,3]]=file_excel.iloc[:,[2,3]].abs()
col_list = list(file_excel)
col_list[4], col_list[2] = col_list[2], col_list[4]
file_excel.columns = col_list
Perforation=pd.DataFrame(data=None)
for i in wells:
    well_name=pd.DataFrame({'WELLNAME '+i}, columns=[1])
    Perforation=Perforation.append(well_name)
    Perforation=Perforation.append(file_excel.iloc[:,[1,2,3,4]][file_excel.iloc[:,0]==i])
    Perforation=Perforation.append(pd.Series(dtype = 'object'),     ignore_index=True)

def SaveFile():
    Save=fd.asksaveasfile(mode='w',defaultextension=".ev", initialfile=name)
    Save.write(Perforation.to_string(index=False, header=False, na_rep=' '))
    win.destroy()

win = tk.Tk()
path = resource_path("image.png")
photo = tk.PhotoImage(file=path)
win.iconphoto(False, photo)
win.config(bg='#FFC')
win.title('Конвертация в формат .ev')
win.geometry('400x130+500+500')
win.resizable(False, False)

label_1 = tk.Label(win, text = 'Сохранение:',
                  bg = '#FFC',
                  font=('Arial', 10, 'bold'),
                  padx=20,
                  pady=10).pack()
btn_1 = tk.Button(win, text = 'Сохранить как', 
                 command = SaveFile,
                 activebackground = '#6F6',
                 font=('Arial', 12, 'bold'),
                 padx=20,
                 pady=10,  
                 relief = tk.RAISED,
                 bd=2).pack()
win.mainloop()
```

[type of file[0]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VL4s.png)

[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3yFk.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code/error messages/data as images. Post the text directly here on SO. It seems, `file[0]` contains a string like `"ABC"`, so `"ABC".unique()` is not defined. How to address this problem depends on your code that you did not include in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, file is DataFrame where file[0] is the first column (I can't understand how to add my code here right)

Comment: @Mr.T please look at [type of file[0]] image

Comment: Well, we can guess all day long. Please read [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question with a reproducible example.

Comment: @Mr.T added, look

Comment: @Mr.T when I tried to replace on .iloc[:, 0] I got an error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iloc'. I can't understand why it's regarded as str but not a Series

Comment: Are you sure that you did not accidentally change the variable order like `name, file = open()` when calling the function? I still cannot reproduce the error with the information provided.

Answer (score 0):

When I created virtual env I should have added openpyxl module. And I made it and everything is fine now